# How can I synchronize the lifetime of a JWT token with the session lifetime in Next-Auth?

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-auth

synchronization of the session lifetime with the jwt token

I am trying to sync jwt token lifetime with session lifetime, i am trying to do it like this but, i keep getting default cookie lifetime(mouth)

Is it possible to synchronize it somehow? Or only setting maxAge can help me?
used "next-auth": "^4.17.0",

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth/next';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';

import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';
import axios from 'axios';

export default NextAuth({
  session: { /*maxAge: 150,*/ strategy: 'jwt' },
  jwt: {
    secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET
  },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      id: 'login',
      async authorize(credentials) {
        try {
          const token = await axios.post(`${process.env.BACK_API}auth/v1/token/`, {
            password: credentials?.password,
            username: credentials?.email
          });
          if (token) {
            const { exp, user_id, user, roles } = jwtDecode(token.data.access);
            return {
              ...token.data,
              exp,
              user: {
                user_id,
                user,
                roles
              }
            };
          } else {
            return null;
          }
        } catch (error) {
          throw new Error(error.message);
        }
      }
    }),
    CredentialsProvider({
      id: 'signup',
      async authorize(credentials) {
        try {
          return await Auth.signup(credentials);
        } catch (error) {
          throw new Error(error.message);
        }
      }
    })
  ],
  callbacks: {
    jwt: ({ token, user, account, profile, isNewUser }) => {
      if (user) {
        token.accessToken = user.access;
        token.t_exp = user.exp;
        token.user = user.user;
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token, user }) {
      if (token) {
        const date = new Date(token.t_exp * 1000);
        session.expires = date;
      }

      return session;
    }
  }
});
```